# How to provide different pages on login for different users?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I'm working on web application which has a database

```
             UserName|Password|UserType
             Anil|Anil|Manager
             ghouse|Ghouse|Admin
             raghu|raghu|User
```

Now my task is to provide each user their own page on login...They all have a same login page.

I tried this code it's working fine for two users. What to do if I have more than two users?

```
         SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=DebitCareBankApp;Data Source=SSDEV7-HP\\SQLEXPRESS");
        string cmdStr = "select LoginType from Login where UserName='" + TxtUsername.Text + "' AND Password = '" + TxtPassword.Text + "'";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdStr, con);
        con.Open();
        Object TypeUser = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        con.Close();
        if (TypeUser != null)
        {
            LblError.Visible = false;
            LblError.Text = "";
            if (TypeUser.ToString() == "Manager")
                Response.Redirect("~/CallingAgents/CallingAgents_Login.aspx");
            else
                Response.Redirect("~/UserRegistrationForm.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            LblError.Visible = true;
            LblError.Text = "Invalid Credentials Entered, Try again";
        }
```

Comment: Is it really user specific or user type specific?

Comment: can any 1 help me with the code..

Comment: thanks to all guys who are tryin to help me out..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should create a common class where insert your user type on successful login.
In that common class redirect it to respective page.

On successful login:

```
 Response.Redirect(clsCommon.GetDefaultPage(userType));
```

your commaon class code:

```
 public static string GetDefaultPage(string userType){
        //Default Redirects
        Dictionary<string, string> userInfo = new Dictionary<string, string>(){
{"Manager","~/ManagerLogin.aspx"},                                  {"Admin","~/AdminLogin.aspx"},                         
                          {"User","~/UserLogin.aspx"}
                                 };
            return userInfo[roleName];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using struts then you can redirect to different pages depending upon some Id. In actionforward you can achieve so. Or you can get some values from the url and try to redirect it

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be to use the Login-control and provide event handlers for the `Authenticate` event and the `LoggedIn` event. But i think it would be worth while for you to check out the capabilities of the asp.net membership system.

Comment: The database structure does not look like Membership provider. I think  login functionality is done by hand.

Comment: Yes there is no membership provider here @rwarzycha

Comment: @Anil: if you have to use your own table, consider implemeneting your own memeberhip and role providers.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are not using [Membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648345.aspx) provider and make your login functionality by hand.

I do not fully understand the purpose of this customization. It make no sense for me. But there are multiple solutions for you:

- convert the login page (aspx) into a user/custom control (ascx) and put in into different pages - *simple, quick but not fully transparent*, **more info [ScottGu](http://webproject.scottgu.com/CSharp/UserControls/UserControls.aspx)**
- use IIS  URL-Rewrite engine to provide multiple entry-points (urls)
  to the  same login page - *clear, recomended***, more info [ScottGu](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx)**

With first scenario you need to check `UserType` for credentials given by the user and confront it with page Url (aspx). In the second scenario, you need to obtain `Request.RawUrl` which contain base Url and make simple `case`.

Comment: @Anil Correct me if i am wrong. Each and every one of user need to have own page ?

Answer (score 0):

Make use of sessions.

For a workaround, you can follow this:

+provide the same login page.
+Ask for username and password.
+use a drop down for selecting the usertype (ie Admin or Manager or User).

So based on the selection from drop down list you process the request.

I hope this helps.